# Python Google PubSub set the acknowledge deadline from subscribe()

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm subscribing to data using `subscribe()` (below).

Occasionally I receive messages out of order and I disregard them, hoping for them to be redelivered 'soon'.

Is there a way to set the `ackDeadline` from `subscribe()`? I can only see it available for `streaming_pull()`.

Code:

```
subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, subscription_id )
streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are wanting to delay redelivery of the message so you can process it at some point in the future. If that is the case, what you want to do is set a retry policy on your subscription (see "Retry policy" in the [subscription properties](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#using_subscription_properties)). This will cause Cloud Pub/Sub to exponentially back off delivery of messages that are nacked. Then, within the code in callback, you can nack a message by calling `message.nack()`.

Note that Cloud Pub/Sub does offer [ordered delivery](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering), which might be a better fit if you want to process messages in order rather than nack and wait for redelivery in order.